# Can I increment my for loop with multiplication? ti-84

Tags: for-loop, calculator

I'm relatively new to programming on the TI-84 and was wondering if I would be able to increment my for loop with multiplication instead of addition. So far, I haven't seen anything that says I can or can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a problem.

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i *= 2 )
Console.WriteLine ( i ) ;
```

Output:

```
#1
#2
#4
#8
#16
#32
#64
```